# Spring Mongo Query by Example on Sub document

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to do a query by example on a sub document in MongoDB using Spring Data Mongo.

Assuming the object in the database looks something like this:

```
{
   _id : ObjectId("..."),
   child : {
      attribute1 : "value1"
   }
}
```

I would like to pass an example of the child to then filter the collection by that. I tried this:

```java
Criteria.where("child").elemMatch(Criteria.byExample(sampleObject))
```

This seems to generate the correct query for MongoDB, but it seems that `$elemMatch` only works on array fields.

Then I tried:

```java
Criteria.where("child").alike(Example.of(sampleObject))
```

That results in an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: json can't serialize type : class org.springframework.data.domain.example
```

Comment: There's a bug in the `QueryMapper`. I opened [DATAMONGO-2314](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2314) to tackle the issue.

Comment: Oh, wow, thank you!